# llvmlite-0.31.0 - OSError: Could not load shared object file: libllvmlite.so

Tags: aws-glue, numba, llvmlite

I am using the wheel files of numba-0.48.0 and llvmlite-0.31.0 downloaded from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/llvmlite/#files) for Python 3.6. as I am trying to execute it via AWS Glue Python Shell Job. When I execute the job, I get the following error:

```
"Could not load shared object file: 
{}
".format(_lib_name))
OSError: Could not load shared object file: libllvmlite.so
```

I have tried using egg files as well, but the error is still the same. Any help to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue Spark jobs does not support loading of python packages that use c-bindings yet

Comment: > You can use Python extension modules and libraries with your AWS Glue ETL scripts as long as they are written in pure Python. C libraries such as pandas are not supported at the present time, nor are extensions written in other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am using AWS Glue Python shell job here. Any suggestion for that? Thanks

Comment: However, Python shell job supports pandas now as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#python-shell-supported-library).

Comment: With the spark jobs, I've included the wheel files for dependencies in a zip file and referenced the zip file as extra python files. However, this is because we do a full pip download and setup then zip everything. Hope this helps.

Comment: Have done the same for Glue Python shell job, but this particular library is giving error. Others work fine. Have you tried with numba and llvmlite?